# Edit a image upon uploading

Tags: ee3, file-manager

Is it possible to upload an image with the ability to edit it's opacity, screen tints, etc? (Not just cropping?) Do I really need an add-on for that?

-signed 
A Struggling novice of EE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use an add-on.  A very powerful image adjustment add-on for EE is [CE-Image](http://docs.causingeffect.com/expressionengine/ce-image/index.html).

As far as I am aware, there are no interactive image-editing add-ons for EE.

HTH